# Removing obsolete comments

Tags: support

Now that this is avp, can we have some effort to remove obsolete "this is off-topic" comments on migrated questions?

I worry that this site will seem even more unwelcoming than SEs sometimes do if practically every question is painted with the off-topic brush.

Would it be considered OK for me (and others, obviously) to use my flag allowance to ask mods to attend to this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, flag these comments for removal.

Removing obsolete and resolved comment inquiries is useful and *explicitly* encouraged.

[**Should moderators delete obsolete comments?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77373/should-moderators-delete-make-correction-done-comments)

Answer (score 2):

That would be helpful, that way we mods don't have to go find them all ourselves.

...Assuming everyone's ok with deleting these comments.  So far I've just been adding an additional comment saying that the question is now on-topic.

Comment: I really think that the off topic comments are very distracting, and are no longer relevant.  It is my understanding that we are supposed to be keeping the SE sites clean and relevant.  Therefore, I feel that they should be deleted.